# Failure tolerance not working as expected in Springboot's batch process

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm developing an Springboot's batch process, which should be tolerance to a single exception (OptimisticLockingFailureException), and do not tolerance to any other kind of exception. For this reason, I'm doing the following:

```
steps.get("stepName")
            .<LegacyUser, User>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(legacyUserReader)
            .processor(legacyUserToUserProcessor)
            .writer(userWriter)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipLimit(2)
            .skip(OptimisticLockingFailureException.class)
            .build()
```

However, this code is making the batch process tolerant to any kind of exception. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `this code is making the batch process tolerant to any kind of exception`: How did you come to such a conclusion? The code you showed will skip only `OptimisticLockingFailureException` and it subclasses. As a side note, `OptimisticLockingFailureException` is a transient exception, so I would use a retry instead of a skip in your fault-tolerant step.

Comment: Because I've executed that code forcing another kind of exception, and the process doesn't fail

Comment: Well in that case, your other exception is making a `OptimisticLockingFailureException` happen in the end, which is obviously skipped (according to your configuration) and the process does not fail. A `OptimisticLockingFailureException` usually happens when the commit fails. Please share your configuration and a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to help you.